# Were are fields of an object allocated?

Tags: java, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am learning the Java language. The variable declared in the class for example int b=17 as an attribute; not in a particular method nor static without calling the new constructor to store it in heap. By default, it is stored where during the execution of the program?

Comment: dynamic == heap

Comment: It's not stored anywhere, it's just a declaration. You need to do a `new` to allocate storage for the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a class that looks like this:

```
class Foo {
   int a;
   int b = 17;

   Foo() {
     this.a = 5;
   }
}
```

When you compile it, it will turn into something like this:

```
class Foo {
   int a;
   int b;

   Foo() {
     this.b = 17;
     this.a = 5;
   }
}
```

So as you can see from here, until you call the constructor, no initialisation is taking place, i.e. there's nothing to store.

Now if your question is about how the constructor knows it needs to use the numbers `5` and `17` specifically, those are part of your compiled class file, loaded with the class.